# Generate 3 PWM signals with a freq2 kHz and duty cycles 10% on P1.4 and 30% on P1.3 and 60% on P1.2 using TimerA in UP mode&OUTMOD_7 signal

Tags: c, embedded

I'm using and MSP430F5529 dev board, a created PCB and CCS to program. My code is as follows:

```
#include <msp430.h>


int main(void)
{
   
    WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;       //stop watchdog timer
    
    P1SEL |= BIT2;                  //configure P1.2 as TA0.2
    P1DIR |= BIT2;                  //P1.2 is output (compare mode)
    P1SEL |= BIT3;                  //configure P1.3 as TA0.3
    P1DIR |= BIT3;                  //P1.3 is output (compare mode)
    P1SEL |= BIT4;                  //configure P1.4 as TA0.4
    P1DIR |= BIT4;                  //P1.4 is output (compare mode)

    TA0CCR0 = 999;                  //CCR0 is used to generate the desired period
    TA0CCR2 = 599;                  //CCR2 is used to generate 0.60 duty cycle
    TA0CCR3 = 299;                  //CCR3 is used to generate 0.30 duty cycle
    TA0CCR4 = 99;                   //CCR4 is used to generate 0.10 duty cycle


    TA0CCTL2 = OUTMOD_7;            //PWM 2
    TA0CCTL3 = OUTMOD_7;            //PWM 3
    TA0CCTL4 = OUTMOD_7;            //PWM 4

    TA0CTL = MC_1 + TASSEL_2 + TACLR|ID_2;
    _BIS_SR(LPM0_bits+GIE);
}
```

Not a single LED turns on using this code and I am unsure of how to fix it.

Comment: read **whole** documentation

Answer (score 0):

You return from main() in a bare metal MCU program, so it will crash & burn before it gets a chance to do anything meaningful.

The most common way to write main() in freestanding programs is:

```
void main (void)
{
   ...

   for(;;)
   { 
     // kick watchdog here
     ...
   }
}
```

Notable, this never returns from main() but stay in the "for-ever" loop.

`void main (void)` is an implementation-defined form supported by every embedded systems compiler out there. (To use this form on gcc, you have to compile with `-ffreestanding`.)